# Create two new branches with specific commits from a dev branch

Tags: git, github

I have created a project using Xamarin Studio for a multi-platform app, I did it using a 'dev' branch but after the job was finished I thought it would be better [for clearance and a easy reference] to have two different branches besides master and dev: iOS and Android for commits related to each platform.

Is there a way at this point of the project that I can clone the dev branch, and delete all the commits non-related to this platform?

This is what i currently have:

`dev -- Android commit -- Android commit -- iOS commit -- Android commit`

And this what I want to achieve:

```
  /-- iOS Branch -- iOS Commit 1
dev -- Android commit 1-- Android commit 2 -- iOS commit 1 -- Android commit 3
  \-- Android branch -- Android commit 1 -- Android commit 2 -- Android commit 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing and have access to the command line, you can do this by creating each branch you want from your last commit and doing

`git rebase -i dev`

This will show you a list of commits in vim and you can delete the ones you want to skip.

Answer (score -1):

You can use GitKraken Tool, it will ease your daily command line syntax to GUI based application.

For reference: https://www.gitkraken.com

With the help of Gitkraken you can simply create multiple branch on single click event.